# Создание графического приложения C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Пишу программы для универа, всегда обходился консолью, а тут понадобилось сделать программу в которой выводится декартова система координат на которой рисуется ответы решения уравнения, в консоли естественно такое делать неудобно и не красиво будет.

Подскажите самый простой способ реализовать это. Думаю самый простой это Visual C++ и среда CLR в Visual studio, но может есть попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую использовать Qt - это простой в изучении фрэймворк для создания графических приложений и не только. В данный момент является одним из самых популярных в своем роде. В вашем случае нужна QGraphicScene - дальше, думаю сами разберётесь.

PS Qt хорош, но не следует им злоупотреблять - многие решения в нем просто ужасны (посмотрите на работу с json). Это из-за того, что он писался ещё до 98-х плюсов, так что многое в нем дублирует стандартные решения, но гораздо более низкого качества (например QMap). К тому же коммерческое использование не является бесплатным (по сути, чтобы Qt использовать бесплатно, нужно чтобы код был ещё и открытым).

Comment: Qt, а не QT только

Comment: Есть в Qt ещё QtCharts, это прямо графики математические, не матлаб конечно, но для простых случаев пойдёт